# What should I do if I get the urge to sneeze or yawn during salat?

Tags: hadith, salat, sunnah, adab

I know that when I sneeze, I should say `Alhamdulillah`.

And If I yawn, then I should cover my mouth with my hand (left) and say `A'oothu billahi mina sh shaithaanir rajeem`.

But, these are all in normal circumstances.

What should I do if I get the urge to do these during salat?

Comment: I have never come across any reference in the Sunnah to support the practice of saying “A`ûdhu bil-lâh min al-Shaytân al-Rajîm” (I seek refuge with Allah from Satan the Accursed) after yawning.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to sneezing and yawning during saying prayers (salah), you should not say any think. Just after sneezing or even after yawning you should keep on your saying prayers. Actually continue from the part of the Salat which you were praying. Otherwise might be it invalidate your saying prayer.

Answer (score 0):

I read that if you yawn during Qiyam, use the back of your right hand to cover your mouth. You use the right hand because in Qiyam it is on top of the left hand so it requires less movement.

If in Ruku', Sujud, Tashahhud, then use the back of the left hand.

Wallahu aalam.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where did you read that? If you could [edit] the source into your answer, it would add credibility.

Comment: Bukhari: Volume 8, Book 73, Number 245:
Narrated Abu Huraira:

The Prophet said, "Allah loves sneezing but dislikes yawning; so if anyone of you sneezes and then praises Allah, every Muslim who hears him (praising Allah) has to say Tashmit to him. But as regards yawning, it is from Satan, so if one of you yawns, he should try his best to stop it, for when anyone of you yawns, Satan laughs at him."

I can't find the specific source of the answer above but it may have been based on this hadith.

Answer (score 0):

Read and Understand whether you are in salah or not
http://kinzulemaan.blogspot.in/2011/06/english-article-sneezing-and-yawning.html

or

Sunan of Abu-Dawood Hadith 5013  Narrated by Salim ibn Ubayd
The Messenger of Allah (saws) said: ‘When one of you sneezes, he should praise Allah (Alhamdolillah).
Because the rite of prayer in itself is process of Remembering, Glorifying and Praising Allah Subhanah….if one perchance happens to sneeze in one’s prayer, the declaring of the Praise of Allah (Alhamdolillah) in one’s own heart during the salah would suffice to fulfill the Sunnah.

Or 
if you want praise him by tongue it is also praising and praising has no fixed way but it just has to be right.

Answer (score 0):

“… as for yawning, then it is from the Shaytaan only …“[al-Bukharee

When one says haa or makes noises whilst yawning the shaitaan (satan) laughs at him/her. So when you feel the urge to yawn try to keep the yawn in.

As for sneezing Allah likes sneezing and dislikes yawning. This is because when you sneeze you praise God but when you yawn it is from Satan.

Answer (score -1):

IN THE NAME OF ALLAH

Hi

Because "even in normal time it isn't obligatory that you should after sneeze or yawn say Alhamdulillah or A'oothu billahi mina sh shaithaanir rajeem" you can don't say these during salat

..::ya Allah::..

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do anything. You cannot and shouldn't delay a sneeze. Yawning tells you something is wrong with your prayer. Just stop and try to concentrate. Just don't pray if you cannot pay attention or feel drowsy. You should be in awe during prayer. (Look 23:2)